# Is rbind error of xts time series a bug or a feature

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have two hourly xts time series that I subset to daily periodicity with `apply.daily`. In the same call I select/subset one column form the data. When I than combine the two daily time series with `rbind`, I receive an error.

I already found a solution, but I was curious whether the behavior is expected or not.

Here is some code to reproduce the error in R version 3.5.2 (Linux Debian) and xts_0.11-2:

```
data1 <- xts(matrix(1:144, ncol = 2), as.POSIXct("2019-05-09 00:00:00") -
          seq.int(60*60, by = 60*60, length.out = 72))
data2 <- xts(matrix(1:144, ncol = 2), as.POSIXct("2019-05-05 00:00:00") -
          seq.int(60*60, by = 60*60, length.out = 72))

colnames(data1) <- c("col1", "col2")
colnames(data2) <- c("col1", "col2")

data1.daily <- apply.daily(data1[,"col1"], colSums)
data2.daily <- apply.daily(data2[,"col1"], colSums)

data.daily <- rbind(data1.daily, data2.daily)
```

Causes the following error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : length of 'dimnames' [1]
 not equal to array extent
```

The main culprit is the first attribute line `chr [1:3] "col1" "col1" "col1"` which looks odd to me:

```
str(data1.daily)

An ‘xts’ object on 2019-05-06 23:00:00/2019-05-08 23:00:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:3, 1] 1452 876 300
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "col1" "col1" "col1"
  ..$ : chr "col1"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

I can easily solve the problem by reversing the steps:

```
data <- rbind(data1, data2)
data.daily <- apply.daily(data[,"col1"], colSums)
```

But I would prefer to store the data once it has a lower frequency.

So the question is not how to solve the problem, but whether this may be a bug or some sub-setting feature for another purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's happening, but removing rownames from the first `xts` object seems to fix it.

```
rownames(data1.daily) <- NULL
rbind(data1.daily, data2.daily)
#                     col1
# 2019-05-02 23:00:00 1452
# 2019-05-03 23:00:00  876
# 2019-05-04 23:00:00  300
# 2019-05-06 23:00:00 1452
# 2019-05-07 23:00:00  876
# 2019-05-08 23:00:00  300
```

Right. Use `sum()`, not `colSums()` in `apply.daily()`.

```
data1.daily <- apply.daily(data1[,"col1"], sum)
data2.daily <- apply.daily(data2[,"col1"], sum)
rbind(data1.daily, data2.daily)
#                     col1
# 2019-05-02 23:00:00 1452
# 2019-05-03 23:00:00  876
# 2019-05-04 23:00:00  300
# 2019-05-06 23:00:00 1452
# 2019-05-07 23:00:00  876
# 2019-05-08 23:00:00  300
```

The error appears to happen in `apply.daily` (or really `period.apply()`), 
when the underlying `sapply()` call returns a named vector. These names later ends up as row names. I wouldn't call this a bug, as using `colSums()` in this setting doesn't make much sense. It should be quite easy, though, to make the function more resilient to errors like this, if that was wanted, but that's up to Joshua.

Comment: This is really weird :)

Comment: Yeah. The row names seems to be introduced by `apply.daily()`, `data1` has no row names.

Comment: Indeed, the colSums makes no sense in this context. I should have changed it to sum when I used the subsetting. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I agree this is weird and confusing.  xts objects should never have rownames.  I'll look at `rbind.xts()` to see if I can make it ignore or drop rownames. `period.apply()` should also be updated to ensure it doesn't create xts objects with rownames.

Comment: I tracked it down to [a bug in the `.xts()` constructor](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/298). This will be fixed in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function for this purpose. I'm not sure, though, if you need the data as `data.frame` or something else. Anyway, I'll provide the former since it was quite a challenge.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(data1.daily, data2.daily), function(x) {
  t <- as.POSIXct(attr(x, "index"), 
                  origin="1970-01-01")
  value <- as.numeric(x$col1)
  return(data.frame(t, value))
}))
res
#                     t value
# 1 2019-05-06 23:00:00  1452
# 2 2019-05-07 23:00:00   876
# 3 2019-05-08 23:00:00   300
# 4 2019-05-02 23:00:00  1452
# 5 2019-05-03 23:00:00   876
# 6 2019-05-04 23:00:00   300

class(res)
# [1] "data.frame"
```